# Google Doodles archive scraping

Tags: web-scraping, download, google-doodle

I am trying to download all (about 2000) of the Google Doodles (not .gif or interactive ones) from their [archive](https://www.google.com/doodles#archive), however I have been having no luck in doing so.

I have tried many scraping commands for terminal, and a few packages from Github, such as [ImageScraper](https://github.com/sananth12/ImageScraper). Through each of the different ways I have tried, I found that either:

- the process just gets stopped after about 100 images using this chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-downloader/cnpniohnfphhjihaiiggeabnkjhpaldj)
- it downloads only some sample images (most command-line tools did this)
- just downloads a couple of images and did not keep going

The archive itself is not indexed from what I can see and each image has its own name, which also makes it harder. To keep viewing more images, the page also needs to keep being loaded as you scroll further down (causing the issue of only downloading a few images). I am also worried that the connection or something may be being cut-off so that these cannot be all downloaded at once, probably to not cause overload (not sure how to fix this though).

I would very much appreciate anyone's help, who has experience in retrieving/scraping such images, given the mentioned problems.

Comment: Do you have experience with any programming language? Have you even tried to build something on your own?

Comment: I have tried to adjust some bash scripts that I had found, but given that I don't have much experience with these, it did not go anywhere unfortunately.